# Understanding the Facebook PageTab app flow

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I have created a simple Facebook Page Tab app, but I'm having difficulty getting my head around the correct flow for getting a user to add the app, and then gain access to their profile.

I'm using the PHP SDK and I've attempted to read, understand and follow the [Facebook Developer Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0), but I'm just not getting it.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: I want users to be able to fill out and submit a simple form via a Facebook Page Tab, and importantly, pre-populate certain fields from the user's Facebook profile.

I have created the Page Tab app, the website, and it works in a fashion, **but the problem is:**

The user visits the Facebook Page Tab, is prompted for basic permissions through the [JS SDK Login Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button) (I couldn't see how to do this with the PHP SDK). Once that's been granted, the user then has to visit the URL generated by `$helper->getLoginUrl`.

**Isn't there some way to make this only one step?**

Comment: _“pre-populate certain fields from the user's Facebook profile”_ – for anything else than the three basic permissions `public_profile`, `user_friends` and `email` for app will have to go through login review first – and Facebook does not grant any of the other permissions for the sole purpose of pre-filling a form with the user’s data.

Comment: Yes the three basic permissions are all that's needed. As I say, it works already, it's just the user experience is very poor.

Comment: You should use `FB.login` method of the JS SDK instead of the login button … in the callback function you can trigger whatever action you like.

Comment: FB.login is part of the JS SDK? And the sample I link to has a callback function, too? Is there any difference?

Comment: Well then I don’t understand what your actual problem is.

Comment: @CBroe I've highlighted the bit where I explain the problem. You can't use a JS function to redirect to the getLoginURL (if that's what you're suggesting), as Facebook has the X-Frame-Options set to DENY.

Comment: Why would you _want_ to redirect to the login URL – login should already have happened when you are using the login button, no? (And of course you _can_ use JS to redirect to the login dialog – you just have to do it in the top window instance. But again, there should be absolutely no need to do this here at all.)

Comment: @CBroe I can't do it in a top.window instance, as it's a Page Tab on Facebook. Anyway, I think you've hit upon the problem: Once logged in, the user should have a valid session/access token, right? For some reason it's not seeing it unless they click on the login URL. I think this is where I've gone wrong :-/

Comment: _“I can't do it in a top.window instance, as it's a Page Tab on Facebook”_ – of course you can. Anyway, I can only repeat it: Just use `FB.login` and be done with it – is the easiest and most convenient way to handle login within a page tab app IMHO.

Comment: @CBroe That would take the user out of the Facebook frame, which I obviously don't want. That's why I can't use it. But you're right, this is the code work really well:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0